# How to get Videos from youtube with offset

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is it possible to query the YouTube API for videos BY X tag from Y user but use an offset so as to build a paginated list. In other words get Videos By X Tag From Y User Offset 10. 
I'd like to do this so I can build a paginated list.

```
catgeory=someTag&user=myUserName&offset=100
```

I am build a Vlog app and loading 380 results at once isn't going to work for me. I need to basically load like 20 at a time.

Comment: This is a great question. Any follow-up?